# In PHP settings, should memory_limit > upload_max_filesize?

Tags: php

I'm trying to allow users to upload large files (64MB) and am planning to change `upload_max_filesize` to 64MB.

However, should I also change `memory_limit` to 64MB or larger?

Is `memory_limit` connected to `upload_max_filesize`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, it's not necessary.

PHP has different POST readers and handlers depending on the content type of the request. In case of "multipart/form-data" (what is used for sending files), [`rfc1867_post_handler`](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/main/rfc1867.c?revision=302387&view=markup#l755) acts as a mixed reader/handler. It populates both `$_POST` and `$_FILES`. What goes into `$_POST` counts towards the memory limit, what goes into `$_FILES` also counts.

However, `$_FILES` has just meta-data about the files, not the files themselves. Those are just written into the disk and hence don't count towards the memory limit.

Answer (score 11):

`post_max_size` must be bigger than `upload_max_filesize`. If a form contains more file uploads then the `post_max_size` must be greater than the sum of them.

The `memory_limit` does not have any significant role in file uploads, as uploaded files are stored in the `/tmp` (Linux) directory, not in memory. If you want to submit large amount of data with form fields (not file uploads) then you need a big `memory_limit` otherwise not.