# Setting PHP tmp dir - PHP upload not working

Tags: php, file-upload, valums-file-uploader

I'm working on file upload via a webpage with a progress bar using [Valums file uploader](https://github.com/valums/file-uploader). Almost everything works fine, but I'm not able to change the default tmp directory, where the file is stored **during** the upload.

Files should be stored in `/upload` directory and not in default system `/tmp` directory, because `/tmp` is mounted in a RAM disk which has its size limited to 4 MB and user will be uploading files around 10 MB.

I've searched lots of webpages, but none of solutions worked.
I've set temp directory in `php.ini`:

```
upload_tmp_dir =/upload
```

I've set permissions to the `/upload` dir, and apache is owner of the file, so the directory is definitely writable by PHP.

I've set the target path in file uploader to `/upload`, because I want the files to be stored after the upload also in this directory. The final result is small files are being uploaded successfuly, but files larger than 4 MB fail to upload-the only reason of this behaviour that comes to my mind is that files are stored in `/tmp` during upload. To be sure, I've checked it with `sys_get_temp_dir()` and the result was `/tmp`-so PHP ignores my php.ini directive or there is some other way to set where files are stored during upload.

Oh, and the last information: `open_basedir` isn't set, so the PHP access to disk is only limited by file permissions.

Comment: Did you restart your server (sorry for this silly question) ?

Comment: There are no silly questions, just silly answers :). Yes, I've done it many times while trying to solve the problem and trying different solutions.

Comment: Did you check that php is not installed as cgi mod ? (From doc : *If the directory specified here is not writable, PHP falls back to the system default temporary directory*)

Comment: Can you check also `upload_tmp_dir` in `phpinfo()` ?

Comment: Okay, now my turn for stupid question: how am I supposed to check if php is installed as cgi mod?

Comment: You can check this with phpinfo or in apache conf

Comment: `upload_tmp_dir` in `phpinfo()` is `/upload/`, so that's OK. The PHP is probably cgi module, because I've found in `apache.conf` the following line: `LoadModule php5_module lib/httpd/modules/libphp5.so`. Am I right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16961/discussion-between-soju-and-wookie88)

Comment: It's not CGI, but the PHP5 Apache module. And if upload_tmp_dir = /upload/ then it won't work, since upload_tmp_dir requires an absolute and writeable path, failing both will make PHP fall back to the standard /tmp/ dir.

Comment: I've written in question that I've set the permissions to the `/upload` dir, so the apache is owner of it. If I set the permissions, I obviously created the directory before :).

Comment: you say on chat that `it's embedded linux modem` /tmp is on RAM, where is /upload?   did you solve this yet?  post your solution here please, as an anwser and accept it

Comment: OK, thanks for reminding me that :)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

The problem described here was solved by me quite a long time ago but I don't really remember what was the main reason that uploads weren't working. There were multiple things that needed fixing so the upload could work. I have created checklist that might help others having similar problems and I will edit it to make it as helpful as possible. As I said before on chat, I was working on embedded system, so some points may be skipped on non-embedded systems.

- Check `upload_tmp_dir` in php.ini. This is directory where PHP stores temporary files while uploading.
- Check `open_basedir` in php.ini. If defined it limits PHP read/write rights to specified path and its subdirectories. Ensure that `upload_tmp_dir` is inside this path.
- Check `post_max_size` in php.ini. If you want to upload 20 Mbyte files, try something a little bigger, like `post_max_size = 21M`. This defines largest size of POST message which you are probably using during upload.
- Check `upload_max_filesize` in php.ini. This specifies biggest file that can be uploaded.
- Check `memory_limit` in php.ini. That's the maximum amount of memory a script may consume. It's quite obvious that it can't be lower than upload size (to be honest I'm not quite sure about it-PHP is probably buffering while copying temporary files).
- Ensure that you're checking the right php.ini file that is one used by PHP on your webserver. The best solution is to execute script with directive described here http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-ini-loaded-file.php (`php_ini_loaded_file` function)
- Check what user php runs as (See here how to do it: [How to check what user php is running as?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771586/how-to-check-what-user-php-is-running-as) ). I have worked on different distros and servers. Sometimes it is `apache`, but sometimes it can be `root`. Anyway, check that this user has rights for reading and writing in the temporary directory and directory that you're uploading into. Check all directories in the path in case you're uploading into subdirectory (for example `/dir1/dir2/`-check both `dir1` and `dir2`.
- On embedded platforms you sometimes need to restrict writing to root filesystem because it is stored on flash card and this helps to extend life of this card. If you are using scripts to enable/disable file writes, ensure that you enable writing before uploading.
- I had serious problems with PHP >5.4 upload monitoring based on sessions (as described here http://phpmaster.com/tracking-upload-progress-with-php-and-javascript/ ) on some platforms. Try something simple at first (like here: http://www.dzone.com/snippets/very-simple-php-file-upload ). If it works, you can try more sophisticated mechanisms.
- If you make any changes in php.ini remember to restart server so the configuration will be reloaded.

Comment: `memory_limit` is not a problem for uploads. See  http://stackoverflow.com/a/5828654/956397

Comment: If you do not plan to read the whole file in PHP, you're right. However, it's good to keep this point in checklist to keep it more universal.

Comment: nice list :D, but any specific reason for the php-ini-loaded-file link to point to the polish php.net? ;)

Comment: Lol, polish version was not translated, so it was identical to English version at the time of writing this post. Fixed now.

Comment: Note: `open_basedir` can be set using `ini_set`.

Comment: **Note** that if `upload_tmp_dir` is "***no value***" (the default), then [php reverts](https://www.php.net/manual/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir) to the system default temporary directory, which you can find out with [`sys_get_temp_dir()`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.sys-get-temp-dir.php).

Answer (score 3):

I struggled with this issue for a long time...
My solution was to modify the php.ini file, in the folder that contained the php script. This was important, as modifying the php.ini at the root did not resolve the problem (I have a php.ini in each folder for granular control).
The relevant entries in my php.ini looked like this.... (the output_buffering is not likely needed for this issue)

```
output_buffering = On 
upload_max_filesize = 20M 
post_max_size = 21M
```

Answer (score 1):

create php-file with:

```
<?php
    print shell_exec( 'whoami' );
?>
```

or

```
<?php echo exec('whoami'); ?>
```

try the output in your web-browser.
**if the output is not your user example:
www-data**
then proceed to next step

open as root:

> /etc/apache2/envvars

look for these lines:

> export APACHE_RUN_USER=user-name
>
> export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=group-name

example:

> export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
>
> export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data

where:

username = your username that has access to the folder you are using
group = group you've given read+write+execute access

change it to:

> export APACHE_RUN_USER="username"
>
> export APACHE_RUN_GROUP="group"

if your user have no access yet:

> sudo chmod 775 -R "directory of folder you want to give r/w/x access"

Comment: @Wookie88 actually gave almost all the solutions to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was selinux...

Go `sestatus`.

If `Current mode: enforcing` then `chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/html`

Comment: Please give us some explanation

Comment: Temporarily disable selinux first to see if this is even the issue; "setenforce 0". The chcon -R is recursively setting the context for files in html directory.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue for 2 days but now finally it is working.

Step 1 : create a php script file with this content.

```
<?php 
echo 'username : ' . `whoami`;
phpinfo();
```

note down the username.
note down open_basedir under core section of phpinfo.
also note down upload_tmp_dir under core section of phpinfo.

Here two things are important ,
see if upload_tmp_dir value is inside one of open_basedir directory.
( php can not upload files outside open_basedir directory ).

Step 2 : Open terminal with root access and go to upload_tmp_dir location.
( In my case "/home/admin/tmp". )

```
  => cd /home/admin/tmp
```

But it was not found in my case so I created it and added chown for php user which I get in step 1 ( In my case "admin" ).

```
  => mkdir /home/admin/tmp
  => chown admin /home/admin/tmp
```

That is all you have to do to fix the file upload problem.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, it was the open_basedir which was defined. I commented it out (default) and my issue was resolved. I can now set the upload directory anywhere.