# Temp dir in php.ini not working?

Tags: php, apache

I have the following script:

```
<form method=post enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type=file name=test><input type=submit></form>
<?php
echo sys_get_temp_dir();
echo '<br/>';
echo ini_get('upload_tmp_dir');
echo '<br/><pre>';
print_r($_FILES);
echo '</pre>';
```

This is the output:

```
/var/tmp/
/opt/httpd/tmp
Array
(
     [test] => Array
     (
        [name] => the-doors-logo.jpg
        [type] => image/jpeg
        [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpyeE7CX
        [error] => 0
        [size] => 80635
    )
)
```

In PHP.ini the tmp_upload_dir is set to '/opt/httpd/tmp'.

Can anyone explain to me how PHP can give me two different 'tmp' folders, while the tmp_name in my FILES is still in /tmp?

Comment: more info in the answer here as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12531408/setting-php-tmp-dir-php-upload-not-working

Comment: I've checked all items on the checklist, but nothing has changed so far..I'll debug some more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `upload_temp_dir` have been specified in your `php.ini`, php will use this, unless it is not specified, not exist or unwritable, php will use default system temp dir.