# What is the risk in file upload forms if I rename the file and move it somewhere else

Tags: php, forms, security, file-upload

I'm reading about security stuff for PHP and my biggest concern now is the users file upload form. I've read a lot that some users may upload files that seems to be something else by changing the extension or even manipulating the header and the mimetype. I understand this.

But my question is how will this be an issue if I rename any uploaded file and move it to a directory that they do not know.

Please let me know if this will be enough or not, and if not, just give me some headline of what extra security checks should I perform

Thanks a lot

Comment: That really depends on how you are using those files and whether the processing of those files is dependant on file extensions/mime type.  There is not enough information to give you an answer.

Comment: For example asking the users to upload their CVs and I will download them and view them later. I do an extension and a mimetype check before uploading, then just rename them and throw them in some folder.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what your online application is looking to achieve. If you wish to limit access directly to files which are uploaded, then you should set the folder permissions for the parent folder of the uploaded area to block user access. Then in your database you can record to path and only host the files through the http response. This will ensure that no files are accessed which could be potentially harmful, and also that users can still upload what they feel. As an extra step, you could add an erroneous file extension to each file while it is hosted and then remove it when it is served.

Answer (score 0):

You might run an antivirus scan daemon in the background like avscand, configured. for scanning and moving infected files to a quarantaine directory. This ought to prevent delivering infected files later back to the people. Configure automatic virus database updating. A bit back that I did do such things, so investigate.

A simple renaming of the file name to one with safe characters should be sufficient; per user separated of course.

Answer (score 0):

To have a more secure site the following needs to happen:

- Due to the nature of security, this list will need be updated every so often.
- Set the `upload_max_filesize` to something sensible
- Install an Antivirus on the server
- Set the `upload_tmp_dir` to something sensible, that the user may not access. See [Setting PHP tmp dir - PHP upload not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12531408/setting-php-tmp-dir-php-upload-not-working)
- Have your form you upload files (which you already have done)
- Your form handler should:

  - Run a `file` command to get the type of the data without executing it
  - Reject random files
  - The PHP interpreter will validate the file size
  - Run the virus scanner on the file
  - Do a file rename to ensure the filename is clean (if you need to reference things, it is convenient to rename the file to the primary key of your attachments table)
  - Move the file to a location that isn't accessible by the client (but move it, so if a later upload comes in with the same name nothing happens)
  - When you move the files, ensure they don't have execute permissions