# how to set and get temp folder/file for file upload in php

Tags: php, file-upload, temporary-files

I was using the system default temp folder (C:\Xampp\tmp) for file uploads. But now I need to specify a temp folder to store the temp files before upload. 
Is this the right function?

```
ini_set('upload_tmp_dir','../../tempuploads');
```

And how to get the file from there?

Till now I was using this:

```
$file_tmpname = $_FILES["ctrlFileUpload"]["tmp_name"];
```

I hope this is possible.

Comment: Check this answer

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12531408/setting-php-tmp-dir-php-upload-not-working][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12531408/setting-php-tmp-dir-php-upload-not-working

Answer (score 0):

It's not temp file "before" upload but temp during and just after upload.
If your ini_set works file tmp_name will be okay and you just have to use move_uploaded_file after that tu push your file in a correct f

Comment: you probably dint understand what I need. I need to get this file from the temp folder so that I can use it to post to another server.

Comment: but why the temp dir is important if you just need to retreive the file ? You can't just get it, put it in a regular folder (not a temp one), and then move to the other server ? I don't know what you mean by "temp folder to store the temp files BEFORE upload...

Comment: I have set the temp dir in php.ini for XAMPP. Can you tell me where would I need to set the temp dir for a linux server?

Answer (score 0):

You can set upload_tmp_dir in the php.ini file:
Set upload_tmp_dir to a safe location

```
upload_tmp_dir = /var/www/foo.bar/sessions
ini_set(‘upload_tmp_dir’, ‘/path/to/dir’);
```

The setting can also be applied in apache’s httpd.conf file, or an .htaccess file:

```
# Set upload_tmp_dir to a safe location
php_value    upload_tmp_dir    /var/www/xxx.bar/sessions
```