# how to set a temp upload directory in php

Tags: php, file

I try to do a simple upload file and I want to fix the upload directory to upload the file but I’ve tried many ways to do it and I got this error
`: failed to open stream.`

I’ve tried like this `'/html5unchained/imgs/'`and this `C:/wamp/www/html5unchained/imgs/`and this `C://wamp//www//html5unchained//imgs//`

```
$uploaddir = 'C:\wamp\www\html5unchained\imgs';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

move_uploaded_file($uploadfile, $uploaddir);
```

i've tried all the posiblities 
any help please

Comment: The first argument to `move_uploaded_file` must be `$_FILES['userfile']['temp_name']`

Comment: @SelaYair Does `C:\foo` look like Unix?

Comment: does the folder exist? do a chmod 777 to get all rights just once like so hmod($uploaddir, 755);// run this just once and retry

Comment: the same problem :/ @KA_lin

Comment: @KA_lin chmod does not exist in windhoos environment

Comment: @karimkarim U have to use the path in $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] if u want to use `move_uploaded_file`. See example @docs : http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: @DarkBee: So you are are saying I can`t use this in my PHP scripts: <?php chmod($uploaddir, 755);?>  ?

Comment: @ka_lin u can use it but if u are running in Windows the chmod will not affect the file. Windows uses ntfs

Answer (score 0):

The location for  the uploaded files on the server can be configured with  [upload_tmp_dir](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir) configuration option..

Comment: i want to do a temporary one

Comment: you need to check upload_tmp_dir,post_max_size,open_basedir  configurations are configures properly ..check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12531408/setting-php-tmp-dir-php-upload-not-working