# Different downloaded file depending on the server

Tags: php, symfony, file-upload, php-ini

I use this code with `Symfony 2.8`:

```
protected function getFiles(FileBag $bag)
{
    $files = array();
    $fileBag = $bag->all();
    dump($fileBag);
    ....
}
```

In my dev environnement (`Ubuntu 16.04`, `PHP 5.6`, `Apache 2`), `$fileBag` is good:

```
array:1 [▼
  "listing" => array:1 [▼
    "image" => array:1 [▼
      "new" => array:1 [▼
        0 => UploadedFile {#14 ▼
          -test: false
          -originalName: "logo2.gif"
          -mimeType: "image/gif"
          -size: 7719
          -error: 0
          path: "/tmp"
          filename: "phpPymk91"
          basename: "phpPymk91"
          pathname: "/tmp/phpPymk91"
          extension: ""
          realPath: "/tmp/phpPymk91"
          aTime: 2017-04-26 14:49:16
          mTime: 2017-04-26 14:49:16
          cTime: 2017-04-26 14:49:16
          inode: 278115
          size: 7719
          perms: 0100600
          owner: 33
          group: 33
          type: "file"
          writable: true
          readable: true
          executable: false
          file: true
          dir: false
          link: false
        }
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

But in the server (azure `Ubuntu 14.04`, `PHP 5.5`) I have this result:

```
array:1 [▼
  "listing" => array:1 [▼
    "image" => array:1 [▼
      "new" => array:1 [▼
        0 => UploadedFile {#14 ▼
          -test: false
          -originalName: "logo2.gif"
          -mimeType: "application/octet-stream"
          -size: 0
          -error: 1
          path: ""
          filename: ""
          basename: ""
          pathname: ""
          extension: ""
          realPath: "/var/www/html/web"
          aTime: 1970-01-01 01:00:00
          mTime: 1970-01-01 01:00:00
          cTime: 1970-01-01 01:00:00
          inode: false
          size: false
          perms: 00
          owner: false
          group: false
          type: false
          writable: false
          readable: false
          executable: false
          file: false
          dir: false
          link: false
        }
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

path, size, mimeType... are not good.

php.ini look the same.

Have you an idea?

Comment: It seems you aren't saving the image, check the save path.

Comment: @PedroLobito: I'm Ok with you, but how can I check that?

Comment: @PedroLobito: `upload_tmp_dir` are empty for both, I put `/tmp ` in php.ini in the server, but there is the same result....

Comment: are you sure php have write access on the directory you are trying to write to? also the directory exists?

Comment: @katona.abel:`/tmp`exist and I can right: `drwxrwxrwt   3 root root 4096 Apr 26 13:54 tmp/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was missing `output_buffering = On` in the `php.ini`

Thank's for suggestions and https://stackoverflow.com/a/37595453/3351765