# Image is not uploading in the uploads folder

Tags: php, forms, image, upload

On clicking the submit button all my data and the image name is going into the database (using phpmyadmin) but the image is also supposed to go into a folder called 'uploads' which is not happening.

Here is my registration form code blogger_register.php

```
<?php
    require "connect.php";
    session_start();

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $target="uploads/".basename($_FILES['image']['name']);

        $bname=$_POST['bname'];
        $blogname=$_POST['blogname'];
        $contact=$_POST['bno'];
        $email=$_POST['bmail'];
        $blogtype=$_POST['blogtypes'];
        $username=$_POST['buser'];
        $password=$_POST['bpass'];
        $password2=$_POST['bpass2'];
        $prooftype=$_POST['prooftypes'];
        $proofno=$_POST['proofno'];
        $bloglink=$_POST['link'];
        $image=$_FILES['image']['name'];
        $bio=$_POST['text'];

        if($password==$password2)
        {
             $sql="select * from brg WHERE `buser`='$username'";
             $query_run=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
             if(mysqli_num_rows($query_run)>0)
             {
                echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("username already exists") </script>';
            }
            else
            {
                $sql="INSERT into `brg` VALUES ('','".$bname."','".$blogname."','".$contact."','".$email."','".$blogtype."','".$prooftype."','".$proofno."','".$username."','".$password."','".$bloglink."','".$image."','".$bio."')";
            $query_run=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
            if($query_run)
            {
                    header("Location: dashboard.php");
              }
            else
            {
                echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("error") </script>';
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Password does not match") </script>';
    }   
}
?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Blogger Registration Form</title>
    <style type="text/css">

    form {
        border: 3px solid #777;
        border-radius:20px;
        width:60%;
        margin-left:20%;
    }

    h1{
  color:black;
  text-align:center;
  <!--font-family:cursi;-->
  font: 400 15px/1.8 Lato, sans-serif;
  letter-spacing:10px;
  <!--letter-spacing: 5px;-->
    font-size:20px;
   }

input[type=text], input[type=password] {
    width: 20%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

button {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 20%;
}

body{
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#fff;
    color:#000000;
    font: 400 15px/1.8 Lato, sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    font-size:20px;
    }

button:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.imgcontainer {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 24px 0 12px 0;
}

img.avatar {
    width: 40%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.container {
    padding: 16px;
}

span.psw {
    float: right;
    padding-top: 16px;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    span.psw {
       display: block;
       float: none;
    }
    .cancelbtn {
       width: 100%; 
    }
 }

.container{
    text-align:center;
 }


</style>

</head>
<body>
<h1>BLOGGER REGISTRATION FORM</h1>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="blogger_register.php" method="post">
    Name: <input type="text" name="bname"><br/><br/>
    Name of Blog: <input type="text" name="blogname"><br/><br/>
    Contact no: <input type="text" name="bno" maxlength="12"><br/><br/>
    Mail-id: <input type="email" name="bmail"><br/><br/>
    Blog Type: <select name="blogtypes" placeholder="CHOOSE YOUR TYPE">

                <option values="sports"> SPORTS BLOG </options>
                <option values="food"> FOOD BLOG </options>
                <option values="event"> EVENT BLOG </options>
                <option values="arts"> ART BLOG </options>
                <option values="fashion"> FASHION BLOG </options>
                <option values="travel"> TRAVEL BLOG </options>
                <option values="photo"> PHOTO BLOG </options>
                <option values="book"> BOOK BLOG </options>
                <option values="tech"> TECH BLOG </options>
                <option values="music"> MUSIC BLOG </options>
                <option values="movie"> MOVIE BLOG </options>


            </select> <br/><br/>
Enter username: <input type="text" name="buser" ><br/><br/>
Enter password: <input type="password" name="bpass" ><br/><br/>
Re-enter password: <input type="password" name="bpass2" ><br/><br/>
Blogger ID Proof: <select name="prooftypes" placeholder="CHOOSE YOUR TYPE">

                <option values="aacrd"> AADHAR CARD </options>
                <option values="voter"> VOTER ID </options>
                <option values="pan"> PAN CARD </options>
                <option values="pass"> PASSPORT </options>
                <option values="dlin"> DRIVING LICENSE </options>

            </select> <br/><br/>
ID Proof Number : <input type="password" name="proofno" required><br/><br/> 
Blog Link: <input type="text" name="link"><br/><br/>    
            *Bio should have a maximum of 140 characters<br>
Blogger's image:<input type="file" name="image"<br/><br/>           
Bio: <textarea  name ="text" rows=4 col=4 maxlength=140> </textarea  required/ ><br/><br/>



    <button class="button button1" name="submit">SUBMIT</button>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you checked this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12531408/setting-php-tmp-dir-php-upload-not-working

Comment: please refer to [Move Uploaded File](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a file upload script to upload images rather than hand coding it. This guy does a neat little script which is really easy to use. https://github.com/aivis/PHP-file-upload-class

As far as your question goes, I see nowhere where you are actually writing the image to any directory.

Comment: I did, in $target

Comment: @Samriddha : no, in your code, you don't get the uploaded file -> check [Move Uploaded File](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)