# Issues upload files on Ubuntu using PHP

Tags: php, ubuntu

I am having an issue uploading files using PHP. Based on my research the user of the apache service needs to have permissions to the folder that files need to be uploaded to. I have done that as shown below

`drwxrwxrwx 2 admin www-data 4096 Jun 13 01:59 temp`

However when I try to upload the file the process times out and what is left in the directory is this

`-rw------- 1 www-data www-data 79 Jun 13 01:54 POST0yS17Q` the POST0yS17Q is just an encrypted file id.

Can anyone help as to why the files are not uploading? Please note the same code works on a Windows server fine. So I have doubts that the code itself is an issue.

Comment: Does your PHP code check for upload errors? `$_FILES['upfile']['error']`

Comment: There is too much potential reasons without a minimum code sample. Please provide something

Comment: Not sure what else to provide as the code works on other servers. The website works fine also the only issue is the file upload and I am unable to find any errors in the error log to provide either.

Comment: Does the uploaded file end up in the `upload_tmp_dir` folder?

Comment: Another possibility is that the filesize exceeds the configured limit. I found a list that may help troubleshooting the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12531408/setting-php-tmp-dir-php-upload-not-working

Answer (score 0):

Set `file_uploads = On` in your php.ini file

Comment: Yes I set the config on the php.ini file

Comment: did you restarted your apache after that