# Error 500 internal server error - apache2 - forum ipb

Tags: php, apache, http, forum

I know there are a lots of topic about this error but didn't find a solution yet...
I re-installed a new version of php (5.4.9) on linux and of apache (2.0), all build by me.

I installed wordpress and it works perfectly, but when I try to log or open my old forum (invision power board) an error occoured: Error HTTP 500 (Internal Server Error).

The directory of this forum is /forum
Permissions of the folder is: 0755
My .htaccess in root is

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^old/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteBase /
```

And my httpd conf directory is

```
<Directory />
#Options FollowSymLinks
#Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Mod rewrite works perfectly with wordpress, the only problem is with this old forum (with many data saved), any solution to fix this problem?

Comment: Do you have any error in Apache error logs ?

Comment: A *500 Internal Sever Error* is ***always*** an invitation to look into the servers error log. It contains more information. As this is PHP, it's also highly likely that it is because of a *Fatal Error in PHP*, so ensuring that PHP error logging is enabled and looking into the PHP error log is very useful, too. [More about the 500 Internatl Server Error](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13940190/367456)

Comment: That's the other problem, I haven't got any error.log. Neither where is build apache (/usr/local/apache2), neither with command "locate/find" in the shell

Comment: @MarcelloChristopharVecchio: Contact your system administrator. She/He knows where that error log is. If you administer that system on your own, you *should* known yourself where you find that. If not, check the apache configuration file what you've got configured. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/logs.html - If you have really disabled apache error logging (which I guess is not the case, but just to extrapolate your last statement), then enable it! Yes, that simple it is. Good luck and have fun troubleshooting your issue.

Comment: Ok, I found the log, but there aren't any notification about /forum. Just a minor errors about the missing of favicon.ico.

Comment: Then you didn't find the right error log.  Keep looking.