# fastcgi 500 failure

Tags: php, http, cgi, fastcgi

we are running windows server 2012, with IIS 8 and php

all of a sudden the site went down with this error message:

```
HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
The FastCGI process has failed frequently recently. Try the request again in a whileMost likely causes:
IIS received the request; however, an internal error occurred during the processing of the request. The root cause of this error depends on which module handles the request and what was happening in the worker process when this error occurred. 
IIS was not able to access the web.config file for the Web site or application. This can occur if the NTFS permissions are set incorrectly. 
IIS was not able to process configuration for the Web site or application. 
The authenticated user does not have permission to use this DLL. 
The request is mapped to a managed handler but the .NET Extensibility Feature is not installed. 
 Things you can try:
Ensure that the NTFS permissions for the web.config file are correct and allow access to the Web server's machine account. 
Check the event logs to see if any additional information was logged. 
Verify the permissions for the DLL. 
Install the .NET Extensibility feature if the request is mapped to a managed handler. 
Create a tracing rule to track failed requests for this HTTP status code. For more information about creating a tracing rule for failed requests, click here. 
 Detailed Error Information:
Module    FastCgiModule 
Notification    ExecuteRequestHandler 
Handler    PHP_via_FastCGI 
Error Code    0x80004005 
Requested URL    http://thesite:80/index.php 
Physical Path    C:\inetpub\wwwroot\index.php 
Logon Method    Anonymous 
Logon User    Anonymous 
 More Information:
This error means that there was a problem while processing the request. The request was received by the Web server, but during processing a fatal error occurred, causing the 500 error. 
View more information »

Microsoft Knowledge Base Articles:

294807
```

i would be most grateful on direction on what i need to do to start troubleshooting this and getting the website back up?

Comment: Microsoft Knowledge Base Articles: 294807 -- A *500 Internal Sever Error* is ***always*** an invitation to look into the servers error log. It contains more information. As this is PHP, it's also highly likely that it is because of a *Fatal Error in PHP*, so ensuring that PHP error logging is enabled and looking into the PHP error log is very useful, too. [More about the 500 Internal Server Error](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13940190/367456)

Comment: @hakre i have not been able to find the server logs!!

Comment: @hakre I have received this error as well and there are no fatal PHP errors. this is related to IIS. restarting the IIS server got everything up and running again. at this point unsure why it happened

Comment: @MikeMurko: The fatal PHP errors in case of a 500 are "only" highly likely - it's not *always* a fatal error in PHP ;). First look into the error log of the webserver, it might tell you more, but I'm not firm with IIS.