# Why does the official PHP manual incorrectly state, “Generally speaking, 'memory_limit' should be larger than 'post_max_size'?”

Tags: php, lamp

I am posting this question here after [seeing this recent SuperUser question on the role `memory_limit` plays in file upload limits](https://superuser.com/q/1351721/167207).

The official PHP manual states the following under [`post_max_size`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size)

> Generally speaking, `memory_limit` should be larger than `post_max_size`.

If you understand PHP on some level and what `memory_limit` is versus `post_max_size` this official advice makes utterly no sense whatsoever. `memory_limit` is a setting that is concerned with PHP process memory limits and `post_max_size` is simply concerned with the max size of items being uploaded via PHP to a filesystem.

Now granted, one can POST a large to a PHP script and have it stored in PHP memory. But pretty much nobody does that. When the vast majority of files are POSTed to a PHP script, that file is streamed through PHP and saved to the file system.

So why then is this “Generally speaking…” advice being given? Or am I completely off my rocker after 20+ years of PHP development and somehow I have been able to upload huge files to LAMP stack applications without having `memory_limit` exceed `post_max_size`?

If found [a similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5106871/117259) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5828654/117259) as well [as this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5106986/117259) that confirms what I am saying. And heck, [here is another answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3651195/117259) that touches on the topic where the answer clearly states, “No.”

So why then is the official PHP manual stating `memory_limit` has anything to do with `post_max_size`?

And yes, I understand there are *some* cases in which this “Generally speaking…” advice is valid, but I am finding it confusing how many online sources (see above) contradict what is said in the PHP manual. Perhaps that “general” advice should be made to be more specific for different usage cases?

Comment: `post_max_size` is not limited to files being uploaded. What if for some unholy reason your site has a form which POSTs 20 MBs of text from a `<textarea>` to the server but your memory limit is 12 MB?

Comment: It would depend on what type of data is being posted. If you aren't expecting file uploads (many sites don't), then limiting the post_max_size to something that can completely fit in memory (e.g. the $_POST array) isn't a bad idea.

Comment: Where does PHP store raw POST data? Is it stored entirely in memory or it writes to the filesystem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because if you use the `$_POST` array it needs to be stored inside the memory, especially for large `POST` data. Therefore it needs to fit into memory.

You also could use the stream wrapper `php://input` to reduce memory usage instead of `$_POST`.

Comment: The php manual is correct. There are many reasons to use this structure. This answer shows but one example.